# How can I calculate a campaign goal ongoing?

Tags: statistics

I work for a non-profit and we are continuing a campaign to serve 1000 children at $29 a month. As of today we have the funds to serve 398 children based on an average from the last 12 months. My difficulty is how I can continue to update this number and reflect the true status of our campaign.

Problem 1.
Some of our gifts are one-time, some are annual and some are monthly. If someone commits to monthly sponsorship of $29 and I put that number into our rolling 12 month average it doesn't truly show that we've moved from 398 children sponsored to 399. Instead it shows that we've moved from 398 to 398 & 1/12 children sponsored.

Problem 2. 
We could resolve this problem by taking any new monthly commitments and multiplying them by 12, then doing the rest of the math, but this only works on month 1. In month 2, that donation would fall off and be counted as `$29` for month 1 and `$29` for month 2 (which is still only 1/6th a child).

I should mention that not all gifts that have come into our system have been labeled as one-time, annual, monthly. We didn't start this until about a month ago.

Any new insight into this problem would be great. If I've not been clear or I need to clarify the problem, please ask me. Thanks

Comment: are you trying to support 1000 children in perpetuity or over some finite horizon?

Comment: @Bey in perpetuity

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have figured it out.

Step 1. Separate all the donations for the last 12 months into two groups.

Group A: One-time and annual gifts.

Group B: Monthly gifts

Group A: Add all the gifts together, then divide by 12.

Group B: Total only the last months gifts

Take the result from Group A and Group B and that is the monthly total, then divide by 29 and you'll have the total served. If there are quarterly gifts then they'd need to be put into a third group and averaged over a rolling 90 days.